# How to get all the keywords based on topic using topic modeling?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, lda, topic-modeling

I'm trying to segregate the topics using lda's topic modeling.

Here, I'm able to fetch the top 10 keywords for each topic. Instead of getting only top 10 keywords, I'm trying to fetch all the keywords from each topic.

Can anyone please suggest me regarding the same...

## My Code:

```
from gensim.models import ldamodel
import gensim.corpora;
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer, TfidfTransformer;
from sklearn.decomposition import LatentDirichletAllocation
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore",category=DeprecationWarning)


def load_data(filename):
    reviews = list()
    labels = list()
    with open(filename, encoding='utf-8') as file:
        file.readline()
        for line in file:
            line = line.strip().split(' ',1)
            labels.append(line[0])
            reviews.append(line[1])

    return reviews
data = load_data('/Users/abc/dataset.txt')
#print("Data:" , data)

def display_topics(model, feature_names, no_top_words):
    for topic_idx, topic in enumerate(model.components_):
        print ("Topic %d:" % (topic_idx))
        print (" ".join([feature_names[i]
                        for i in topic.argsort()[:-no_top_words - 1:-1]]))


no_features = 1000

tf_vectorizer = CountVectorizer(max_df=0.95, min_df=2, max_features=no_features, stop_words='english')
tf = tf_vectorizer.fit_transform(data)
tf_feature_names = tf_vectorizer.get_feature_names()

no_topics = 5

lda = LatentDirichletAllocation(n_topics=no_topics, max_iter=5, learning_method='online', learning_offset=50.,random_state=0).fit(tf)
no_top_words = 10


display_topics(lda, tf_feature_names, no_top_words)
```

Comment: All the keywords from a topic is basically all your words in your corpus that is coming under that topic. How would that help you?

Comment: Actually, I have a generic dataset. So, what I'm planning to do is, extract only specific domain dataset from the original dataset. For that , I chose LDA topic modeling. So, I need all the words in my corpus that is coming under that specific  topic.

Comment: Actually, the top 10-15 words are the words that will probably be in your 90% of your text. So, you can just write rules on top it to categorize the text and then can find all the words in each topic

Comment: @RahulAgarwal, thanks a lot for your suggestion.