# how to change default number_words in LDA

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, lda, topic-modeling

i am able to extract topics from LDA model using gensim. when i print topics ,it is displaying topics with 10 number of words by defaults. i want to show 15 words in one topic.i tried to change it but still i am getting 10 words per topic.how can i change this default behavior?

here is the code:

```
for n, topic in model.show_topics(num_topics=-1, num_words=15,formatted=False):
                topic = [word for word, _ in topic]
                cm = CoherenceModel(topics=[topic], texts=documents, dictionary=dictionary, window_size=10)
                coherence_values[n] = cm.get_coherence()
            top_topics = sorted(coherence_values.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
            result.append((model, top_topics))
```

and for printing the topics:

```
pprint([lm.show_topic(topicid) for topicid, c_v in top_topics[:8]])
```

Comment: Check this Question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52385474/how-to-get-all-the-keywords-based-on-topic-using-topic-modeling?noredirect=1#comment91716152_52385474. He has written in a way where you can get the desired number of words. Hope it helps

Comment: @RahulAgarwal that is in sklearn and i am using gensim. also i tried to change the default number of words from 10 to 15 here:for n, topic in model.show_topics(num_topics=-1, num_words=15,formatted=False) but still showing the 10 words per topic

Comment: I know...just posted the link...if you can get some idea from it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is in the show_topic function. You're finding more words for the topic but not displaying them, as show_topic has an optional variable, topn for retrieving the most significant words. The default is 10, so change your code at the print statement to

```
pprint([lm.show_topic(topicid, topn=15) for topicid, c_v in top_topics[:8]])
```

and it should display them all.